# How can i detect AirPods when they connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, airpods

I would like to detect if my AirPods did connect. I was able to do it for any other bluetooth device, but cant find any observers to do the same for AirPods. Any ideas? tnx

Comment: Add some code that you have tried. Also, How you are getting the did connect for any other Bluetooth device?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IOBluetooth framework. There’s a class called [IOBluetoothDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iobluetooth/iobluetoothdevice), which has a type method that allows you to register for device connect notifications.

```
IOBluetoothDevice.register(forConnectNotifications: self, selector: #selector(connectNotifications))
```

From here you can call `isConnected` on your `IOBluetoothDevice` instance and check if it’s connected or not.

Comment: I just noticed you are asking for iOS. I’d look into the CoreBluetooth framework.